# Reference request: free/open source books on intro numerical PDE

Tags: pde, reference-request

I'm interested in finding a **free** online textbook that is an introductory textbook on numerical PDE for engineers. It should cover the basics of finite differences, finite elements, and Fourier series methods for very simple PDE cases, mainly the 1D heat and 1D wave equations, and should *not* be concerned with rigor, proofs of convergence, etc.

The purpose of this request is to find a decent online resource for students to use as an alternative to an official course textbook. The students are undergraduate engineers who have seen multivariate calculus and linear algebra but no other mathematics.

Does anybody have suggestions?

Comment: you can certainly do worse than choosing _Finite Difference and Spectral Methods
for Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations_ by Lloyd Trefethen. The book (1) covers pretty much all the topics you listed above and (2) is _free_ and available for download [here](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/pdetext.html).

Comment: as a sidenote, there is [another free book by the same author](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/ExplODE/) covering ODEs, but it relies heavily on MATLAB (and the latter is, unfortunately, _not_ free).

Comment: @GoHokies Thank you for the suggestion. Trefethen's book is unfortunately too advanced for the intended audience. The students will be undergraduate engineers that only know the basics of multivariate calculus and linear algebra (and nobody masters these subjects after just one semester).

Comment: The suggestion by @GoHokies seems reasonable to me. You could just skip the rigorous parts and focus on the methods. Just for curiosity, are you looking something similar to [12 steps to Navier-Stokes](http://lorenabarba.com/blog/cfd-python-12-steps-to-navier-stokes/)

Comment: @nicoguaro I briefly looked at the Python notebooks in your link and I would say yes, something like that except for FEM and spectral methods for 1D heat and wave. The issue with Trefethen's book is that a student who has just recently been introduced to a topic cannot "just skip" certain parts because they do not know enough to recognize what to skip and what not to.